# In scene kit, adding a physics body manually (in code) to a node, seems to not work? You have to add the physics body in the editor?

Tags: scenekit, game-physics, scnnode

It seems you just can't add a physics body in code.

Not much more can be said than this, has anyone found this issue?

Some example code ...

```
class SomeSceneView:  SCNView {
    public var box: SCNNode!
    
    .. 

    var physBody = SCNPhysicsBody()
    
    private func bringup() {
        box = scene?.rootNode.childNode(withName: "box", recursively: true)
        
        physBody.type = .dynamic
        physBody.isAffectedByGravity = false
        physBody.friction = 0

        box.physicsBody = physBody

        rendersContinuously = true
        play(nil)
    }
}
```

Any experience with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need also to file a `SCNPhysicsShape`.

Try something like this:

```
func makeNode() {
    let node = SCNNode(geometry: SCNSphere(radius: 1.0))
    ...
    node.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .dynamic, shape: SCNPhysicsShape(geometry: node.geometry, options: nil))
    ...
    scene.rootnode.addChildNode(node)
}
```

Comment: that could be it!  checking !!!!!!

Comment: did it work for you?

Comment: YES - BRILLIANT - BOUNTY EN ROUTE

Comment: I have no words.... - thank you!

Comment: ! here's one, @zay !  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75009992